# Loading Text Data from a CSV and Applying a Tokenizer in Keras

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I apologize in advance for a seemingly simply question; however, I am new to using Tensorflow and Keras and I cannot find a solution from tutorials or previously-asked questions.

I'm trying to load a dataset that contains article titles and a sentiment score and use a tokenizer on the text data for classification. My code is as follows:

```
import keras
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras import preprocessing
from keras import models
from keras import layers

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")

!ls drive/'My Drive'/'Dat'/Data

data = pd.read_csv("drive/My Drive/Dat/Data/stock_sentiments.csv", header=[0])

dataset = data.values 

X = dataset[:, :-1]
y = dataset[:, -1]

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000, filters='0123456789!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True) #this code works
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X) #this code returns the error

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X) #this also returns and error

word_index = tokenizer.word_index

word_index
```

When I attempt to fit the tokenizer, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-0c427a3ac01d> in <module>()
      2 
      3 tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000, filters='0123456789!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True) #this code works
----> 4 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X) #this code returns the error

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py in 
text_to_word_sequence(text, filters, lower, split)
     41     """
     42     if lower:
---> 43         text = text.lower()
     44 
     45     if sys.version_info < (3,):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

When I print out X, it returns an array of the titles, separated by commas and [brackets] which is what I'm expecting. When I print out y, it prints an array of 0's and 1's, separated by commas, which I also expect.

I'm certain I'm missing something obvious that's causing this error but I feel like I've hit a dead end. Any help or clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
text = X.reshape(-1)
```

and this solved the problem.